# How to capture the window screen when monitor is disconnected (headless)?

Tags: winapi, directx, screenshot

My application is running on virtual machine and take a screen of window at every one minute. It gives the blank screenshot. Using below code for the same.

```
HWND    hWndCapture     = ::GetDesktopWindow();
HDC     hdcScreen       = ::GetDC(hWndCapture);
HDC     hdcMem          = ::CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);

::BitBlt(
    hdcMem,
    0,
    0,
    Width, //width of region of interest
    Height, //height of region of interest
    hdcScreen,
    X, //left staring point for capture
    Y, //top staring point for capture
    SRCCOPY);
```

Does DirectX can give the correct screenshot while headless mode?

Does Microsoft provide any kernel level API for headless screen capture?

Is there any other way to take screen of window?

Thanks,

Mahen

Comment: Are you sure that's C#?

Comment: Strange looking c#

Comment: Finally i wants to call this API from C#. Currently i make this POC from VC++. So i add a tag for C#. If you think it not relevant then i remove it.

Comment: You are using C, so the question should be tagged C.

Comment: ["The desktop window is the area on top of which other windows are painted."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633504(v=vs.85).aspx) ... are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: My end goal is capture the any application window which give as a input.

Comment: LPCTSTR WindowName = "calc";
HWND Find = ::FindWindow(NULL,WindowName);

Comment: In another words: Do you need to get screenshot of desktop? This is correct? Or content of some selected window?

Comment: yes , i need content of some selected window.